# sIFR - override link click with onRelease?

Tags: ajax, flash, sifr

I've got sIFR setup to replace a navigation menu (looks pretty slick).  It's individually replacing the LIs and their internal links.  I have an onRelease tag that throws properly, extracts the actual href link address, all good so far.  I want to tie this into an AJAX page loader, with backwards-compatability (+SEO) for the individual pages being able to load themselves.  I've tried return false like I would for standard links, no dice.

I'm assuming it doesn't work because it's onRelease, not onClick or something BEFORE it is already changing the page?  onClick doesn't seem to be a valid sIFR function, documentation at http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/JavaScript+Methods says onRollOver, onRollOut, and onRelease.  It would be a shame to have to pitch my entire AJAX system, there is hopefully a good workaround!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really an option to prevent the default behaviour. You can change it in `sIFR.as` though. Assuming the `<li>` contains *just* a `<a>` remove the following around line 505:

```
    getURL(sIFR.instance.primaryLink, sIFR.instance.primaryLinkTarget);
```

That will prevent sIFR from following the URL when you click on the link. It'll still work with right-click though, but you might be able to fix that by changing (line 508):

```
  menu.customItems = menuItems;
```

to

```
  menu.customItems = [];
```